# Book recommendation in analysis before graduate school

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request, book-recommendation

I've got a few months to go before I enter in graduate school, but I have to say that my math background is not as good as I would like. Thus, I would like to take the opportunity to strengthen it and work on undergraduate analysis. I had in mind to work on the Rudin book I've heard so much about, the book is very concise and covers a wide spectrum of mathematical analysis (and a bit of topology) seen in undergraduate so I thought it was suitable for what I want to do with it.

But I'd like to hear your opinions and recommendations if you've ever been in this situation and/or know of any other cool books (I'am also interested in functional analysis and especially Hilbert spaces so...) for the self-taught to get through the summer.

Thank you a lot !

Comment: A lot of people like Tao's analysis book too. If you struggle with baby Rudin you could always switch to Abbott for something a bit less terse. My undergraduate analysis class used Rosenlicht and that was pretty good. For functional analysis you can check out Kreyszig and Rudin, but you should probably get through measure theory first (again Rudin, or Folland).

Comment: There’s also Stein & Shakarchi. The real analysis volume. I find this an easy read very self-contained.

Comment: @csch2 Thank you for the comment !  I had thought of Tao's book but since there's material I've already seen in it, I thought of something more concise like the Rudin! As for the theory of measurement, I agree with you. The Lebesgue integral is covered in Rudin but not in depth (no study of Lp spaces, for example).